# Netsuite - Saved Search - String All True Results of Case Formula

Tags: case, netsuite

Hoping someone can help me out with a NetSuite question, and I apologize in advance if i’m misusing some lingo.

I am creating a item based saved search and one of my formula (text) result fields can have multiple true values when I apply my case formula.  I’m look to combine all the true results of this formula into one comma separated string, instead of a new item row for each true value.

```
sku     contact     type
123     John S      Owner
123     Jane S      Clerk
123     Jack S      Clerk
```

Formula (text) - Custom Label Field Name = Contact Name

```
Case when {type} = ‘Clerk’ then {contact} end
```

Currently my results generate a item (sku) row for each case of clerk:

```
Sku     Contact Name
123     Jane S
123     Jack S
```

I’m looking for my results to be a single string

```
Sku     Contact Name
123     Jane S, Jack S
```

I know the case function noted above will not string the results by itself; I originally intended to use the group by and max summary types, but I only get one Contact Name result.

Any solutions or work arounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented Netsuite function [`NS_CONCAT()`](http://blog.prolecto.com/2014/05/16/reveal-both-aggregate-and-detail-in-netsuite-saved-search/) (similar to Oracle's undocumented [`WM_CONCAT()`](http://psoug.org/definition/wm_concat.htm)) that does exactly this. You would group your results by the SKU column, and add formula field with the formula `NS_CONCAT({contact})` and the summary type set to Minimum or Maximum.

[According](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/searches-list-views/35943-aggregate-concatenation-on-searches) to some Netsuite employees on the Netsuite User Group, the  [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function should also work now, and offers more flexibility (if you wanted a delimiter other than a comma for example).

Answer (score 0):

There are certain grouping functionality available for saved search results, but I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.

If you group your results by Sku, you will get one line per Sku but concenating the contact names from different line results I don't think is possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your SaveSearch's Filter look for **mainline** and try to set either true(Yes) Or false(No).